# Triggering a video autoplay based on scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, video.js

I am writing a script that uses the Wipe animation from the scrollorama.js script. I am hoping to be able to implement a video to autoplay at certain markers in the scroll depth: ie, when a video page has wiped out another, and is now fully viewable.  I have figured out how to measure scroll depth, i am successfully logging it in my console. I have figured out how to measure how deep i have scrolled, but maybe i am so tired, i don't know how to ask the video to play automatically at the scroll depth. I hope this is a legal question, and that I can get some assistance. Has anyone out there tried this before?  Here is the code thus far.

`enter code here` $(document).ready(function() {

$(window).scroll(function(e) {

```
  var scrollAmount = $('body').scrollTop();
  console.log(scrollAmount);
```

});

```
    var controller = $.superscrollorama();
    var pinDur = 800;   
    // create animation timeline for pinned element
var pinAnimations = new TimelineLite();

//pinAnimations.append([TweenMax.to($('#green'), .5, {css:{top:0}})], .5)
pinAnimations.append([TweenMax.to($('#intromovie'), .5, {css:{top:0}})], .5 )
pinAnimations.append([TweenMax.to($('#red'), .5, {css:{top:0}})], .5) 
pinAnimations.append([TweenMax.to($('#blue'), .5, {css:{top:0}})], .5 )
pinAnimations.append([TweenMax.to($('#movie1'), .5, {css:{top:0}})], .5);
pinAnimations.append([TweenMax.to($('#history1'), .5, {css:{top:0}})], .5);
//pinAnimations.append(TweenMax.to($('#pin-frame-unpin'), .5, {css:{top:'100px'}}));


controller.pin($('#content_wrapper'), pinDur, {
    anim:pinAnimations, 
    onPin: function() {
        $('#content_wrapper').css('height','100%');
    }, 
    onUnpin: function() {
        $('#content_wrapper').css('height','1000px');
    }


});

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out, so i answer my own question with the help of a lot of other answers patched together here!

If anyone is interested, the html was simple:

```
    <div id="videoHolder"></div>
```

Jquery was also simple:

```
        $(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function(e) {

        var scrollAmount = $('body').scrollTop();   
        console.log(scrollAmount);


    if(scrollAmount >="theamountyouwant" && scrollAmount <= "theotheramountyouwant") {


        $("#videoHolder").html(
            '<video width="1200" height="700" autoplay>' +

         '<source src="http://itp.nyu.edu/~rnr217/HTML5/Week3/video/testopen.webm" type="video/webm"></source>'  +
        '<source src="http://itp.nyu.edu/~rnr217/HTML5/Week3/video/testopen.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>' +

         '</video>');
```

Comment: this is adding the video to the DOM when scrolled to, not autoplaying a video that is already on the DOM, I think that is a better use case since the user will actually see the video in the current position instead of the video appearing suddenly.

Answer (score 1):

**So in this case we can use an integrated JavaScript API namely [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)**. Now our main task is to play the video at an particular position, so for this task we will set up a trigger on the intersectionRatio value.

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll(".mydivTriggerClass");

vid = document.getElementById("myVideoId");

observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  console.log(entries);

  if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0.34) {
    vid.play();
  } else {
    entry.target.style.animation = "none";
  }
});

observer.observe(image);
```

**NOTE**: Please note that the console log entries are optional - its just so that when you inspect you get the info showing where this intersection ratio came from.

For a perfect working example please visit [this link](https://codepen.io/designcourse/pen/RXVdBj?editors=1010).

Answer (score 0):

just add the script from below and add playonscroll param to your video tag anywhere on a page.

As well some times it's required to use different scroll container than body, sometimes its not obvious, so the following code works like a charm for me:

```
setInterval(function () {
    $('video[playonscroll]').each(function () {
        var videoElement = $(this)[0]; 
        var eTop = $(this).offset().top;
        var elementOffestY = (eTop - $(window).scrollTop());
        var videoOffset = [elementOffestY, elementOffestY+$(this).height()];
        if ((videoOffset[0] < 100) && (videoOffset[1] > 350)) {
            console.log('play');
            if (!videoElement.playing) {
                videoElement.play();
            }
        } else {
            if (videoElement.playing) {
                videoElement.pause();
            }
        }
    });
},300);
```

in case if you always use body container for scroll just change setInterval to $(window).scroll

And don't forget to define property for Video tag element:

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLMediaElement.prototype, 'playing', {
    get: function(){
        return (this.currentTime > 0 && !this.paused && !this.ended && this.readyState > 2);
    }
})
```